# Can read opearation cause .lock in unix?

Tags: unix, deadlock

In unix, when `ProcessA` is reading from `FileX`, if `ProcessB` attempts to remove the `FileX`. Would this cause a deadlock on `FileX` ?

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Unix-like_systems) says some stuff.. from which I couldnT carve out an answer for this simple question..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can remove a file whilst another process is reading it. There's no locking by default.

e.g.

```
$ touch a
$ tail -f a
```

and in another prompt

```
$ rm a
```